# Wrap image around a circle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

What I'm trying to do in this example is wrap an image around a circle, like below.

[image: original]

[image: wrapped]

To wrap the image I simply calculated the x,y coordinates using trig.
The problem is the calculated X and Y positions are rounded to make them integers. This causes the blank pixels in seen the wrapped image above. The x,y positions have to be an integer because they are positions in lists.

I've done this again in the code following but without any images to make things easier to see. All I've done is create two arrays with binary values, one array is black the other white, then wrapped one onto the other.

The output of the code is.

[image: example]

```
import math as m
from PIL import Image  # only used for showing output as image

width = 254.0
height = 24.0
Ro = 40.0

img = [[1 for x in range(int(width))] for y in range(int(height))]
cir = [[0 for x in range(int(Ro * 2))] for y in range(int(Ro * 2))]


def shom_im(img):  # for showing data as image
    list_image = [item for sublist in img for item in sublist]
    new_image = Image.new("1", (len(img[0]), len(img)))
    new_image.putdata(list_image)
    new_image.show()

increment = m.radians(360 / width)
rad = Ro - 0.5
for i, row in enumerate(img):
    hyp = rad - i
    for j, column in enumerate(row):
        alpha = j * increment
        x = m.cos(alpha) * hyp + rad
        y = m.sin(alpha) * hyp + rad
        # put value from original image to its position in new image
        cir[int(round(y))][int(round(x))] = img[i][j]


shom_im(cir)
```

I later found out about the Midpoint Circle Algorithm but I had worse result with that

[image: midpoint]

```
from PIL import Image  # only used for showing output as image

width, height = 254, 24
ro = 40

img = [[(0, 0, 0, 1) for x in range(int(width))]
       for y in range(int(height))]
cir = [[(0, 0, 0, 255) for x in range(int(ro * 2))] for y in range(int(ro * 2))]


def shom_im(img):  # for showing data as image
    list_image = [item for sublist in img for item in sublist]
    new_image = Image.new("RGBA", (len(img[0]), len(img)))
    new_image.putdata(list_image)
    new_image.show()


def putpixel(x0, y0):
    global cir
    cir[y0][x0] = (255, 255, 255, 255)


def drawcircle(x0, y0, radius):
    x = radius
    y = 0
    err = 0

    while (x >= y):
        putpixel(x0 + x, y0 + y)
        putpixel(x0 + y, y0 + x)
        putpixel(x0 - y, y0 + x)
        putpixel(x0 - x, y0 + y)
        putpixel(x0 - x, y0 - y)
        putpixel(x0 - y, y0 - x)
        putpixel(x0 + y, y0 - x)
        putpixel(x0 + x, y0 - y)
        y += 1
        err += 1 + 2 * y
        if (2 * (err - x) + 1 > 0):
            x -= 1
            err += 1 - 2 * x

for i, row in enumerate(img):
    rad = ro - i
    drawcircle(int(ro - 1), int(ro - 1), rad)

shom_im(cir)
```

Can anybody suggest a way to eliminate the blank pixels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are having problems filling up your circle because you are approaching this from the wrong way – quite literally.

When mapping *from* a source *to* a target, you need to fill your *target*, and map each translated pixel from this into the *source* image. Then, there is no chance at all you miss a pixel, and, equally, you will never draw (nor lookup) a pixel more than once.

The following is a bit rough-and-ready, it only serves as a concept example. I first wrote some code to draw a filled circle, top to bottom. Then I added some more code to remove the center part (and added a variable `Ri`, for "inner radius"). This leads to a solid ring, where all pixels are only drawn once: top to bottom, left to right.

[image: a solid ring]

How you exactly draw the ring is not actually important! I used trig at first because I thought of re-using the angle bit, but it can be done with Pythagorus' as well, and even with Bresenham's circle routine. All you need to keep in mind is that you iterate over the *target* rows and columns, not the *source*. This provides actual `x`,`y` coordinates that you can feed into the remapping procedure.

With the above done and working, I wrote the trig functions to translate *from* the coordinates I would put a pixel at *into* the original image. For this, I created a test image containing some text:

[image: test image with text]

and a good thing that was, too, as in the first attempt I got the text twice (once left, once right) and mirrored – that needed a few minor tweaks. Also note the background grid. I added that to check if the 'top' and 'bottom' lines – the outermost and innermost circles – got drawn correctly.

Running my code with this image and `Ro`,`Ri` at 100 and 50, I get this result:

[image: round test image]

You can see that the trig functions make it start at the rightmost point, move clockwise, and have the top of the image pointing outwards. All can be trivially adjusted, but this way it mimics the orientation that you want your image drawn.

This is the result with your iris-image, using `33` for the inner radius:

[image: iris to eye mapping]

and here is a nice animation, showing the stability of the mapping:

[image: aww bright light ahead!]

Finally, then, my code is:

```
import math as m
from PIL import Image

Ro = 100.0
Ri = 50.0

# img = [[1 for x in range(int(width))] for y in range(int(height))]
cir = [[0 for x in range(int(Ro * 2))] for y in range(int(Ro * 2))]

# image = Image.open('0vWEI.png')
image = Image.open('this-is-a-test.png')
# data = image.convert('RGB')
pixels = image.load()
width, height = image.size

def shom_im(img):  # for showing data as image
    list_image = [item for sublist in img for item in sublist]
    new_image = Image.new("RGB", (len(img[0]), len(img)))
    new_image.putdata(list_image)
    new_image.save("result1.png","PNG")
    new_image.show()


for i in range(int(Ro)):
    # outer_radius = Ro*m.cos(m.asin(i/Ro))
    outer_radius = m.sqrt(Ro*Ro - i*i)
    for j in range(-int(outer_radius),int(outer_radius)):
        if i < Ri:
            # inner_radius = Ri*m.cos(m.asin(i/Ri))
            inner_radius = m.sqrt(Ri*Ri - i*i)
        else:
            inner_radius = -1
        if j < -inner_radius or j > inner_radius:
            # this is the destination
            # solid:
            # cir[int(Ro-i)][int(Ro+j)] = (255,255,255)
            # cir[int(Ro+i)][int(Ro+j)] = (255,255,255)
            # textured:

            x = Ro+j
            y = Ro-i
            # calculate source
            angle = m.atan2(y-Ro,x-Ro)/2
            distance = m.sqrt((y-Ro)*(y-Ro) + (x-Ro)*(x-Ro))
            distance = m.floor((distance-Ri+1)*(height-1)/(Ro-Ri))
        #   if distance >= height:
        #       distance = height-1
            cir[int(y)][int(x)] = pixels[int(width*angle/m.pi) % width, height-distance-1]
            y = Ro+i
            # calculate source
            angle = m.atan2(y-Ro,x-Ro)/2
            distance = m.sqrt((y-Ro)*(y-Ro) + (x-Ro)*(x-Ro))
            distance = m.floor((distance-Ri+1)*(height-1)/(Ro-Ri))
        #   if distance >= height:
        #       distance = height-1
            cir[int(y)][int(x)] = pixels[int(width*angle/m.pi) % width, height-distance-1]

shom_im(cir)
```

The commented-out lines draw a solid white ring. Note the various tweaks here and there to get the best result. For instance, the `distance` is measured from the center of the ring, and so returns a low value for close to the center and the largest values for the outside of the circle. Mapping that directly back onto the target image would display the text with its top "inwards", pointing to the inner hole. So I inverted this mapping with `height - distance - 1`, where the `-1` is to make it map from `0` to `height` again.

A similar fix is in the calculation of `distance` itself; without the tweaks `Ri+1` and `height-1` either the innermost or the outermost row would not get drawn, indicating that the calculation is just one pixel off (which was exactly the purpose of that grid).

Comment: Thank I'll take a look later.

Comment: This is absolutely the best way to approach the problem. You can get an even better result by using interpolation on the calculated coordinates from the source image, instead of just taking a single pixel of input for each output.

Comment: @MarkRansom: right. That way you don't get the extreme pixelization at the largest magnification visible in the Text version at the outer ring, and it helps removing artifacts in the innermost circle. ... I was contemplating area sampling for this, but that adds a lot of code, only semi-related.

Comment: @RadLexus What is causing those yellow streaks in the inner circle of the GIF?

Comment: @jackjameshoward: a bad online PNG-to-GIF converter, alas. But at least it's not an artefact of my drawing method.

Comment: @RadLexus For me, the code you posted doesn't work. The line `pixels[int(width*angle/m.pi) % width, height-distance-1]` produces a `IndexError: image index out of range`. It gives an index value of -1, if I delete -1 from the end of that line of code then it only draws half a circle.

Comment: @jackjameshoward: ouch. This sounds as if there is still an off-by-one error somewhere. I'll have to take a closer look. What image size and values of `Ro` and `Ri` does this happen with?

Comment: @RadLexus, I just copied the code you posted above and used the original iris image I posted. Ro = 100.0, Ri = 50.0, (256,64)

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need is a noise filter. There are many implementations from which I think Gaussian filter would give a good result. You can find a list of filters [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFilter.html). If it gets blurred too much:

- keep your first calculated image
- calculate filtered image
- copy fixed pixels from filtered image to first calculated image

Here is a crude average filter written by hand:

```
cir_R = int(Ro*2) # outer circle 2*r
inner_r = int(Ro - 0.5 - len(img)) # inner circle r
for i in range(1, cir_R-1):
    for j in range(1, cir_R-1):
        if cir[i][j] == 0: # missing pixel
            dx = int(i-Ro)
            dy = int(j-Ro)
            pix_r2 = dx*dx + dy*dy # distance to center
            if pix_r2 <= Ro*Ro and pix_r2 >= inner_r*inner_r:
                cir[i][j] = (cir[i-1][j] + cir[i+1][j] + cir[i][j-1] +
                    cir[i][j+1])/4


shom_im(cir)
```

and the result:

[image]

This basically scans between two ranges checks for missing pixels and replaces them with average of 4 pixels adjacent to it. In this black white case it is all white.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That was surprisingly simple to implement. Thanks it worked almost perfectly. The only trouble I had was this line `cir[i][j] = (cir[i-1][j] + cir[i+1][j] + cir[i][j-1] + cir[i][j+1])/4` because I want to handle tuples so I can represent RGBA  values

Comment: Yes it is most of the time troublesome to play with multiple channels. Most of the time I convert them to 32 bit integer values and reverse after all pixel manipulations are done :)