# Getting a incorrect picture output when running my self-made rotation algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, image-manipulation, image-rotation

In order to better understand how image manipulation works, I've decided to create my own image rotation algorithm rather than using cv2.rotate() However, I'm encountering a weird picture cropping and pixel misplacement issue.

I think it may have something to do with my padding, but there may be other errors

```
import cv2

import math

import numpy as np
# Load & Show original image
img = cv2.imread('Lena.png', 0)
cv2.imshow('Original', img)

# Variable declarations
h = img.shape[0]  # Also known as rows

w = img.shape[1]  # Also known as columns

cX = h / 2 #Image Center X

cY = w / 2 #Image Center Y

theta = math.radians(100) #Change to adjust rotation angle

imgArray = np.array((img))

imgArray = np.pad(imgArray,pad_width=((100,100),(100,100)),mode='constant',constant_values=0) 
  #Add padding in an attempt to prevent image cropping

# loop pixel by pixel in image
for x in range(h + 1):

 for y in range(w + 1):

  try:
   TX = int((x-cX)*math.cos(theta)+(y-cY)*math.sin(theta)+cX) #Rotation formula 

   TY = int(-(x-cX)*math.sin(theta)+(y-cY)*math.cos(theta)+cY) #Rotation formula

   imgArray[x,y] = img[TX,TY]

  except IndexError as error:

   print(error)

cv2.imshow('Rotated', imgArray)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

## Edit:

I think the misplaced image position may have something to do with lack of proper origin point, however I cannot seem to find a functioning solution to that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I didn't dive in the math part of the domain, but based on the given information I think the **matrix rotating** formula should work like this:

**UPDATE:**

As I promised I dived a bit into the domain and got to the solution you can see as follows. The main trick that I've swapped the source and destination indices in the looping too, so the rounding doesn't mean any problem ever:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np


# Load & Show original image
img = cv2.imread('/home/george/Downloads/lena.png', 0)
cv2.imshow('Original', img)


# Variable declarations
h = img.shape[0]  # Also known as rows
w = img.shape[1]  # Also known as columns

p = 120
h += 2 * p 
w += 2 * p

cX = h / 2 #Image Center X
cY = h / 2 #Image Center Y

theta = math.radians(45) #Change to adjust rotation angle

imgArray = np.zeros_like((img))  

#Add padding in an attempt to prevent image cropping
imgArray = np.pad(imgArray, pad_width=p, mode='constant', constant_values=0)   
img = np.pad(img, pad_width=p, mode='constant', constant_values=0)   

# loop pixel by pixel in image
for TX in range(h + 1):
    for TY in range(w + 1):
        try:
            x = int( +(TX - cX) * math.cos(theta) + (TY - cY) * math.sin(theta) + cX) #Rotation formula 
            y = int( -(TX - cX) * math.sin(theta) + (TY - cY) * math.cos(theta) + cY) #Rotation formula

            imgArray[TX, TY] = img[x, y]

        except IndexError as error:
           pass
#           print(error)

cv2.imshow('Rotated', imgArray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
exit()
```

[image]

**Note:** See usr2564301 comment too, if you want to dive deeper in the domain.

Comment: Geeocode! Nice to see you back again :D Such minor changes, such large a result. May I be so rude as to ask what the changes did?

What was the reason for changing the numpy array to zeros_like, doesn't that just fill the entire array with 0s instead of the image value?

I presume you did the +100 to TX & TY in order to move each rotated pixel to the image center, right?

Comment: @MikkelGHansen Please see explanation ;)

Comment: Another amazing job Geeo. Thanks for the clear explaination. I feel dumb working on this for so many hours, so many different methods, for a simple array change + padding compensation issue :P  Now comes the task of erasing the annoying dark spots. Considered thresholding & filtering but grayscale image makes it a tad difficult. Maybe feature finding /shrug

But once again thanks so much for the assistance! :D

Comment: @MikkelGHansen To be honest this is the first time I try to answer in this object i.e . cv2 & matrix rotating etc, but I found it interesting and it really was. If I will have a bit more time, I may rethink my answer a bit and make some update also if needing.

Comment: @MikkelGHansen See my updates in code and description too regarding the padding correction and interpolation.

Comment: You will get a better result if you don't loop over the *source* image pixels, but over the *destination* ones instead. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/38745020/2564301 and my answer therein.